# Output is "1" even if the column is empty for some entries in MySQL database

Tags: sql, database

I have entries on database as shown in the image:

[image]

SQL query is:

```
SELECT Lastname, COUNT(Item) FROM info GROUP By Lastname;
```

The output is:

[image]

Why does it returns "1" even if the "Item" column is blank for the highlighted entries?

Comment: That's not how [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) works.

Comment: Can you provide us the the query for build this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query will give the required result :-

```
select Lastname,count(CASE item WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE item END) item from info  group by Lastname;
```

The reason why you were getting count as 1 for blank is that your data type may be varchar or char.If your data type were int then it must have given count as 0 for blank value.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why I was getting `1` for empty fields. Your solution was best to review the empty fields too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Lastname, COUNT(Item) FROM info where Item is not null GROUP By Lastname;
```

**Update**

```
SELECT Lastname, COUNT(Item) FROM info where Item is not null AND Item <> '' GROUP By Lastname
```

Comment: There is no change in the output. Empty columns are still giving "1". Do I have to change any properties of the `Item` column?

Comment: Are your empty `Item` values `NULL` or are they something else?  This answer should also work for you.

Comment: I try it myself now but on sql server and that worked.

Comment: `create table info(
lastname varchar(12), item varchar(12)
) `

Comment: @the scion After adding `AND Item <> ''` it worked. Edited query: `SELECT Lastname, COUNT(Item) FROM info where Item is not null  AND Item <> ' ' GROUP By Lastname;`

Answer (score 1):

The `COUNT()` function counts *records*, regardless of the value of `Item` in that record.  If you want to ignore `NULL`/empty string, then you can use the following `CASE WHEN` expression to conditionally tally only records with actual values for `Item`:

```
SELECT Lastname, COUNT(CASE WHEN COALESCE(Item, '') = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
FROM info
GROUP By Lastname
```

Comment: I got an error: `#1305 - FUNCTION mydatabase.COALESECE does not exist`. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in there.  Use the `COALESCE()` function.  My answer will cover you whether you actually have `NULL` items, or they are just empty string.

Comment: There is no change in output. I'm still getting the same output similar to the uploaded picture for output.

Comment: You need to tell us what the "empty" `Item` values really are.  Try doing `SELECT * FROM info`, copy an "empty" cell, and see what is in there.

Answer (score 0):

The empty values can be either `NULL` or empty string `''`, so you need to exclude both from your query to avoid counting them:

```
SELECT Lastname, COUNT(Item)
FROM info
WHERE Item is not null
  AND Item <> ''
GROUP By Lastname;
```

Note: if the empty values are something other `NULL` nor empty string `''`, you will have to exclude that. For example, if they are spaces `'   '` or some other invisible characters.

Comment: Addition of `AND Item <> ' '` solved the problem. Thanks buddy